# How do i use multiple filters in FFMPEG?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to get the following done with FFMPEG:

- Use 2 Filters in FFMPEG
- Run it for all .mp4 files in that folder.

Now, the second thing i have already done but for some reason when i am trying to use 2 filters it will only use the first one. The filters should

1. Speed up the video
2. Change the Saturation and Brightness

I've already tried ";" "," and ":" to seperate the filters but somehow its not working. Here is the code:

```
for %%a in ("*.mp4") do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=0.87*PTS[v];[0:a]atempo=1.15[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a];eq=brightness=0.06:saturation=2" output\%%~na.mp4"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
for %%a in ("*.mp4") do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=0.87*PTS,eq=brightness=0.06:saturation=2[v];[0:a]atempo=1.15[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output\%%~na.mp4
```